# How can I add common header to every request in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I need to add a header (or set of headers) for many existing requests (all in workspace except two) and I would like this header to be added as default to new request or be able to add them without rewriting or copying it all.

All I can think of is to use environment variables for the header name and value but if I have multiple headers I would need to add them to every request but it is difficult to maintain.

Is there better way to do this? Is there anything like inheritance for the requests?

Comment: Global / default headers + headers inheritence from groups is something I want to add for a long time. It is still not available. In the next version for sure :) Setting an environment variable is the only thing I can suggest for now.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri looking forward for the next version! And thank you for the last one that made switching environments a lot easier :-)

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Also hoping for that feature! ;)

Comment: @MichaMazaheri this question is 3 years old; I still do not see the possibility to add header to a group of requests in Paw 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri same need here OR as a workaround to make our life easier the ability to do a copy&past of header(s). I mean the full line (name & value) and also be able to copy/past multiple header lines. Thank :)

Comment: This is just a basic feature, I wanted to switch from Postman but alas.

Comment: Hm, adding a custom header for auth on all requests seems pretty basic. Adding those manually to an imported collection from postman is honestly too much work to be bothered.

Comment: Anyone ever have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding it as environment variable and use it for every request.
visit https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments-reusable-presets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).